# Find developer id that sign the ios app programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, code-signing

Is there a way to find the Developer ID that is signed the app programmatically?

For example if I use a certificate and provisioning profile from  mymailId@mailserver.com to sign my app I can find it via a code at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. Its not part of the code. It is bundled as part of the `.IPA`

Comment: I remember that I had seen a code in Internet that fetched provisioning profile at runtime? so if we can find provisioning profile then we can not find developer id?

Comment: The developer ID is not used in the provisioning profile.  You can get the certificate name and the team identifier, but not someones Apple ID.